# Not Equal / Exist in Access Database

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

So I am unable to wrap my brain around this.

I have 2 Tables in my database with matching fields in it

`Table1: ComplaintsLogged` ( This table contains all the data and all records)

`Table2: ComplaintsClosed` (This table only contains the complaints that have been closed)

Now I am trying to run a query which can be represented something like this.

`ComplaintsLogged.status` - `ComplaintsClosed.taskStatus`

Subtract the `closed` status in `ComplaintsClosed` from `ComplaintsLogged` and show me the rest of the records in `complaintsLogged`

both have a common field of complaint No. in them.

Comment: The design of your database doesn't sound right... to make your life easier, you should probably have a single table with a status field, rather than two (or more) tables for each status.

Comment: So Is what you want is to display all the complaints that are not closed?

Comment: @Amber yes that is correct. Display all complaints not closed after matching the closed complaints in both tables and then subtracting that result from the 'ComplaintsLogged' Table

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing what you asked

```
select ComplaintsLogged.id from ComplaintsLogged
where not exists (select 1 from ComplaintsClosed
where ComplaintsClosed.id = ComplaintsLogged.id)
```

Comment: I am trying to compare and contrast data according to status in both tables

Comment: @Hamid Alonso: The above query will give you all the records which exists in ComplaintsLogged which do not exist in ComplaintsLogged - that's what I understand your question to be. If you want to display from that subset only records whose status is 'not closed', then add a 'and' clause to the query outside of the brackets. Your question is not very clear on this point.